# С++ Error: use undeclared identifier 'factory_candy'

Tags: c++

Есть код

```
if (factory_data.count("candys") == 1) auto& factory_candy = get<uint64_t(factory_data["candys"]);
else auto factory_candy = 1;
```

После этого я использую эту переменную. При компиляции пишется, что переменная не определена. Подскажите, как сделать правильно ?

Comment: Определить переменную `factor_candy` до условия `if`: `std::uint64_t factor_candy = 0; if (...) factor_candy = ...; else factor_candy = ...;`. См.: [scope](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope).

Comment: Переменные существуют только внутри фигурных скобок, в которых были созданы. Это грубо говоря. Тело if-а из одной строчки тоже считается, даже если скобки там не написаны.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая вещь, как область видимости. Грубо говоря то, что было создано внутри фигурных скобок, остаётся внутри фигурных скобок. Однако область видимости не ограничивается фигурными скобками, а, как в вашем случае, ещё появляется в условном операторе. То есть ваша созданная переменная внутри условных выражений попросту исчезает в никуда.

Дабы решить проблему, вам нужно объявить переменную заранее вне условного оператора.